# Rails check string for symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm nubbie in rails and ruby
In my app i get data from csv and in some fields of quantities value is 100> and etc. But how to check that? and select only integer(float) part? But note! it can be <20, >30, 30< and so over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have floating point numbers (not just the integer part), you can use a small variant of Justin Ko's solution:

```ruby
values = ["10.1>", "<20.3", ">30.4", "30.6<"]
values.each do |val|
  puts /(\d+\.\d+)/.match(val)[0].to_f
end

# => Output will be 10.1 20.3 30.4 30.6
```

Comment: @pavelby, you can then use `puts /(\d+\.?\d*)/.match(val)[0].to_f` as the regexp.  The numbers will be returned as floats, but this pattern will catch the integers and the floating numbers as well.

Comment: but also how to catch such numbers? so if 10 didn't have ><= we go more, but if has go to you solution?

Comment: @PavelBY, I am not completely sure I understood your question: however, the regexp in my comment above with catch all the numbers (integers as well as the floating point numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to just get the numeric part of the field.

The regex is simply `/(\d+)/`.

Here is an example:

```
values = ['<20', '>30', '30<']
values.each do |val|
    puts /(\d+)/.match(val)[0].to_i
end
# => 20, 30, 30
```